# Home Network File Sharing: Laptop--Cat5-->ISP modem / Google TV-->wireless router--Cat5-->ISP modem

Tags: wireless-networking, file-sharing, wired-networking

My windows 7 PC is connected to my ISP's modem via Cat5.  My wireless router is connected the same way.  The wired LAN is `192.168.1.xxx` and the wireless is `192.168.2.xxx`.  Is it possible to share files with this network configuration?  I've had success with the laptop connected on wireless but sometimes I want the laptop running on the wired connection and not the wireless for other reasons.  When the laptop is on the wired connection, I would still like to be able to access the shared files from the Google TV.

On the Google TV, I'm using the app [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). That app has an `Add New Server` screen where I can input `Domain`, `IP Address`, `Username / Pass` (or anonymous).   I used that feature to add the laptop when the laptop was connected to the wireless network.

So to recap: 
1.) Is it possible?
2.) If it is possible, how do I do it?

**Edit** First I tried to just put the IP of my PC (on wired) into the TV but it said it couldn't find it.  Then I tried to put the the wifi router in the 1.xxx pool but it didn't work (I didn't realize I had to turn off DHCP on the wifi router).  I got it working by adding an entry to the wifi router's routing table so that it could find my PC when it is on the other subnet.  I'm sure @The_aLiEn's suggestion would have been easier but, at this point, its working and I don't want to mess with it any more.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.  What exactly have you tried already? What happened when you tried?  Does your Wifi router have Wireless isolation capabilities?  Is it disabled?

Comment: Why two different subnets? Configure your wireless router to have an IP adress on 1.xxx pool and shut DHCP down on that router. So, wireless router will act like only as an access point and wireless clients will be served with IP addresses from ISP Modem's DHCP server.. All clients will be on the same subnet **logically** and since your wireless router is not a **router** any more, they all will be on the same subnet physically.

Comment: What is wireless isolation?

Comment: Is one way better or faster than the other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two different subnets on this configuration. You can configure your wireless router to have an IP address on the 1.xxx pool and shut DHCP down on that router. This turns your wireless router into a wireless access point. And all clients connected to that access point will be served with IP address from ISP modem's DHCP server.

So logically all clients, both wired and wireless, will be on the same subnet and since wireless router is not a router anymore they all will be on the same subnet physically also.